# Is 'lamented' a dialogue tag?

Tags: dialogue

In these sentences,

> - "I miss having breakfast every day," he lamented.
> - "I miss having breakfast every day." He lamented.

is the first correct? I would say *lamented* **is** a dialogue tag, since if I use the verb *said* or *responded* instead, then it would be a dialogue tag:

> "I miss having breakfast every day," he said.
>
> "I miss having breakfast every day," he responded.

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lament) licenses the use of 'lament' as a quotative verb:  “I've lost my best friend!” she lamented.